# How to register an open generic that accepts parameters in LightInject?

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, light-inject, open-generics

I have the following generic class, which depends on `IBar`:

```
public class Foo<T> : IFoo<T>
{
    public Foo(IBar bar, int value) { }
    
    ...
}
```

I would ***ideally*** register it using something like this in **LightInject**:

```
container.Register<IBar, Bar>();
container.Register<int, IFoo<>>((factory, value) => new Foo<>(factory.GetInstance<IBar>(), value))
```

so that at runtime, I am able to obtain an instance of IFoo with the supplied value:

```
container.GetInstance<IFoo<SomeType>>(42);
```

But this code obviously does not compile due to the use of the open generic `IFoo<>`:

```
container.Register<int, IFoo<>>((factory, value) => new Foo<>(...))
```

If only Foo was not a generic class, this would all work fine as per the official documentation: https://www.lightinject.net/#parameters.

Is there a solution for generic classes? Can this be written any other way and still achieve the same thing? I tried using the following syntax, but I'm loosing the ability to use a delegate that accepts a value (or at least I don't see how to do it)...

```
container.Register(typeof(IFoo<>), typeof(Foo<>));
```

Any idea?

Comment: Light-inject is such a fringe library, there is probably no out of the box way to do this, maybe you should just download the source and implement your own overload, or put in a feature request with the author

Comment: Do you think this could be achieved using another library (.net framework), eg: Unity?

Comment: "at runtime, I am able to obtain an instance of IFoo with the supplied value". It's best to prevent injecting runtime data into a component upon construction. See [this](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/runtime-data/).

Comment: Most DI Containers do not allow to inject runtime data during a resolve, and the ones that do, are limited to injecting that runtime data to the top-most resolved class, which typically makes the usefulness of such feature limited.